# MS-SQL select rows that have no records as null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 3 tables:

```
A) Unit information [Unit]
+-----------+---------+-------+
| record_ID | SN      | Data1 |
+-----------+---------+-------+
|     1     | 123 123 |  info |
+-----------+---------+-------+

B) Test related information [TestingData]
+---------+------------------+-----------+
| SN      | Info1            | Data1     |
+---------+------------------+-----------+
| 123 123 | Some information | Some data |
+---------+------------------+-----------+

C) Join table to more testing information [Link]
+--------+---------+
| LinkID | SN      |
+--------+---------+
|    1   | 123 123 |
+--------+---------+

D) Testing details [Tests]
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
| LinkID | testdate            | Testname  |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
|    1   | 10.05.2015 22:22:00 | AD1       |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
```

Now the tricky part:

I need to get the last record for each LinkID where test name = AD1 for example.

I managed to create a query that does just this, except that it returns no rows in case there was no AD1 named test:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rf2.linkID ORDER BY rf2.testDate DESC) AS rn 
,rf2.*, rs.*
FROM dbo.Unit rs 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.TestingData rf ON ( rs.SN = rf.SN  )  
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Link rf1 ON ( rf.SN = rf1.SN)  
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Tests rf2 ON ( rf1.linkID = rf2.linkID )  
WHERE rf2.testType = 'AD1'   
) T
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY SN ASC;
```

How can I extend (if possible at all) above query so that I will also get rows with null values in case there has not been a testType of AD1?

Reason behind this is that I will need to integrate this part to a larger report, which I will integrate through a join on SN.

Comment: You might want to provide more sample data (with `CREATE` and `INSERT` scripts), and expected results. We only have one example here, however, you're asking us about a way to get other rows; rows that aren't in your sample data. Here is a good place to start: [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: "I have the following 3 tables".  Then you list 4.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get the last record for each LinkID where test name = AD1 for example.

I can't figure out why your question has references to four tables, when one table has all the information you need.  The `full join`s are even less explanable.

This gets the rows from `tests` that you want:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from tests t
where t.testName = 'AD1' 
order by row_number() over (partition by t.linkid order by t.testdate desc)
union all
select t.*
from tests t
where not exists (select 1 from tests t2 where t2.linkid = t.linkid and t.testName = 'AD1');
```

You can also do this with window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by linkid, testname order by testdate desc) as seqnum,
             sum(case when testName = 'AD1' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by linkid) as num_ad1
      from tests t
     ) t
where (l.num_ad1 > 0 and testName = 'AD1' and seqnum = 1) or
      (l.num_ad1 = 0);
```

You can *JOIN* in the other tables, for additional columns you may want.  There is no need for `FULL JOIN`, a `LEFT JOIN` should suffice.

Comment: `TestName` and `TestDate` are in the `Tests` table, not `Links`. But, leaving this typo aside, OP wants to get one row for each `LinkID`, not just a single row for the whole table. Are you sure that `TOP(1)`, even `WITH TIES` would achieve that? Hmm.... I guess, it will. I didn't notice `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER()` in the middle of the query text.  I prefer to put blank lines around `UNION ALL` for readability.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov . . . Thank you (I fixed the table name).  The `TOP (1) WITH TIES` is being used in conjunction with `ROW_NUMBER()`.  Try it on some of your data.

Comment: Now the first part before `UNION ALL` is correct - it selects from `Tests`. But, I think, second part after `UNION ALL` should select from `Links`. The `WHERE NOT EXISTS` part seems to correctly select from `Tests`, though. Once you makes these changes, you should spell out columns explicitly instead of `*` as well, because two parts of `UNION` would select from different tables.

Comment: Overall, upvoted for showing how to use `TOP(1) WITH TIES` instead of subquery with `WHERE rn = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying `where test name = AD1` so I think you should check `Testname` instead of `testType` in the `WHERE` clause as below:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rf2.linkID ORDER BY rf2.testDate DESC) AS rn 
,rf2.*, rs.*
FROM dbo.Unit rs 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.TestingData rf ON ( rs.SN = rf.SN  )  
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Link rf1 ON ( rf.SN = rf1.SN)  
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Tests rf2 ON ( rf1.linkID = rf2.linkID )  
WHERE rf2.Testname = 'AD1'   -- You should use `Testname` instead of `testType`
) T
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY SN ASC;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
rn  LinkID  testdate                Testname    record_ID   SN      Data1
1   1       2015-10-05 22:22:00.000 AD1         1           123 123 info
```